# How to delete duplicate rows using sequelize for Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a model like below:

```
id, flatNo, buildingId
```

I want to delete the duplicate rows while retaining exactly one unique row. How can I do that in sequelize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to Join same table as below:

```
DELETE
FROM
    Table1 a
        USING Table1 b
WHERE
    a.id < b.id
    AND a.flatNo = b.flatNo
    AND a.buildingId = b.buildingId;
```

Comment: This will just delete rows with the same flatNo, right? I want to delete rows with same flatNo and building Id

Comment: You can add buildingid in AND

Comment: I have updated the query based on your requirement.